# When performing OLS regressions why might the strict exogeneity assumption be violated if necessary control variables aren't included?

Tags: linear-regression

I think I just about grasp the basic understanding but it's still confusing me. In my statistics course I'm investigating a hypothetical bone-wasting disease dataset among different population groups, which has a number of geographic controls and the like. I got the question wrong and said that they weren't needed, but my teacher didn't elaborate.  Like why do we need control for different groups in our regression - what do we gain by doing that? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This one is straightforward application of the OLS assumptions.

To take almost straight from undergraduate lecture slides. In OLS you make an assumption about the distribution of of errors - since the errors are joint normal and uncorrelated, which implies that (εi)i∈N is an i.i.d. set. If you don't have control variables it is likely that you are ignoring independent variables that are affecting your dependent variables. Implying that the unobservables between different populations are independent, which appears clearly unrealistic.